# LINQ lambda expression Join method performance

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join, lambda

I've been trying to optimize a JOIN clause using lambda expression and don't really know what is the best in terms of performance. Can anyone advice?

Considering I have two object (particularly DB tables):

- Cars (with CompanyId as part of the PK, as we have more cars for the same company)
- Engines (with both CompanyId and EngineId fields)

I need info from both objects for a particular company.

Now, when I do the join is it best to

1. Do the JOIN on two fields (composite key - CompanyId and EngineId) without a where clause on the Joined table?

```
context.Cars
.Where(w => w.CompanyId == companyId)
.Join(context.Engines, cars => new { cars.CompanyId, cars.EngineId }, eng => new { eng.CompanyId, eng.EngineId }, (cars, eng) => new { // my selection }).ToList()
```

2. Do the JOIN with where clause on the inner table, to restrain the entries (filter the entries), before joining on EngineId alone.

```
context.Cars
.Where(w => w.CompanyId == companyId)
.Join(context.Engines.Where(w => w.CompanyId == companyId), cars => cars.EngineId, eng => eng.EngineId, (cars, eng) => new { // my selection }).ToList()
```

3. Do the JOIN with where clause on the inner table, to restrain the entries (filter the entries), before joining on both CompanyId and EngineId.

```
context.Cars
.Where(w => w.CompanyId == companyId)
.Join(context.Engines.Where(w => w.CompanyId == companyId), cars => new { cars.CompanyId, cars.EngineId }, eng => new { eng.CompanyId, eng.EngineId }, (cars, eng) => new { // my selection }).ToList()
```

To summarize my concerns, is it enough to Join on 2 fields if I have my Engines table indexed with a clustered index for both CompanyId and EngineId? Or is it always better to put a where clause before specifing the keys to join on?

Thanks!

Comment: If there's a FK relationship between Cars and Engine then you should have a Navigation property on `Car` called `Engine` and you can use that instead `Join`

Comment: LINQ to databases converts queries to SQL - you need to examine the SQL sent to your database engine to determine which is most efficient.

Comment: @NetMage. How can I see the equivalent of the SQL code? I can "toString()" it? I know there's a way to catch the query in the SSMS Activity Monitor if that's detected as an expensive query.

Comment: @juharr - thanks! That is helpful :) What if there's no PK-FK relationship?

Comment: LINQPad is a very helpful tool.

Comment: The where clause should be unnecessary, and may actually (depending on database engine) reduce the performance. Database engines can often convert cross join with where to inner join, and may well reduce all three of your queries to the same plan, but you should just do number 1 and let the database engine figure it out.

Comment: @NetMage - thanks! :) That's what I did and I saw an improvement. Have a nice day!